# Animation in iOS with LOTS of high-res images

Tags: ios5, animation, uiimageview

I'm pretty new to iOS programming and I have this problem.

I have a view where the animation is a train rushing past. The frames of the animation are 60ish (1024x768) pngs which I put in an array and then use `[myUIImageView startAntimating]`.

This works beautifully but I have another animation that I want to run later in the same view, which is around 270 pngs of the same resolution, in which the train comes to a stop and the doors open. Adding these images to a `UIImageView` in the same way unsurprisingly makes the app crash. In fact, not adding the first set of images and only adding these images makes the app crash.

What would be the best way to overcome this problem?

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same issue.. if you have solved, will you please help...?

Comment: @Chitra The way I solved it is described below.

Comment: Can whoever downvoted this please explain why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Holding 270 such PNGs should take around 850 mb of memory, so you can't hold them all at once.  I can think of three ways to solve this -

1. Not load all the images at once, but instead only hold (say) 10 images in memory, discarding images that have already been shown and loading new ones from disk.
2. Use a dedicated movie format; these formats have inter-frame compression, where a new frame only holds the difference between it and the previous frame. This obviously reduces memory usage. Take a look at [`libav`'s FAQ](http://libav.org/faq.html#How-do-I-encode-single-pictures-into-movies_003f) to see how to convert a sequence of images into a movie.
3. Reduce the size of the images. If you're not on the iPad, or do not require retina-resolution, reducing the number of pixels will drastically reduce the memory requirements.

Comment: Thanks for this :) So if I went with option one, I would create an array of the first ten images, animate that once, then replace it with the same array but with the next ten images, and animate that once and so on? Do you think that'll work? I'll give it a go and if not I'll try option 2. Thanks again.

Comment: Something like that; you might want to hold two arrays, one which is being displayed, while the other is being loaded with images from disk. Whenever displaying ends, swap the arrays. Hopefully, images will be loaded fast enough. Personally, I would just directly go to displaying a movie. Why do you work with individual images?

Comment: Because that's what I get sent from our designer... and he's away for two weeks. I guess I could try and stitch the images together into a video.

Comment: Well... take a look at `libav` - http://libav.org/faq.html#How-do-I-encode-single-pictures-into-movies_003f

Comment: Cheers. I managed to make the movie pretty simply with a free tool I found on the net. And it plays well. The only thing is, it opens like a normal movie with controls and a progress slider etc and doesn't look like an in-built animation. I guess I'll have to look into that though.